# How do I get spork to respect my run filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spork

I'm using spork to speed up my RSpec tests however I can't get it to reload the filter conditions on each run e.g. `config.filter_run_excluding :slow => true`

Regardless of whether I put these filters into the `Spork.each_run` block or not they only seem to be loaded when it first starts up which is a pain.

Is it possible to get them to be re-interpreted every time?

**My spec_helper file:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
require 'shoulda/integrations/rspec2'


Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'shared/test_macros'
  require 'shared/custom_matchers'
  require "email_spec"

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.include(TestMacros)
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # THESE ONLY SEEM TO BE INTERPRETED DURING PRE-FORK
    config.filter_run_excluding :slow => true
    config.filter_run :now => true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it isn't technically the answer to the question I asked I did find a solution to this.

What I essentially wanted to do was to occasionally focus on a couple of tets i.e. use `config.filter_run :now => true` and then fall back to running all tests when those passed. I found out that you can do this by adding the following self-explanatory config line:

```
config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
```

**Subsequent `each_run` block in `spec_helper`**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # restrict tests to a particular set
  config.filter_run_excluding :slow => true
  config.filter_run :now => true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end
```

What this does is run all of the tests when none of them are eligible via filters. I.e. if you remove `:now => true` from all test blocks then they'll all run. As soon as you add it back in again only the flagged block will run.

Answer (score 2):

`Spork.each_run` isn't being run during prefork, but the code has already been loaded into memory. That means any edits you make won't be seen until you restart spork. Spork does not auto-reload spec_helper.rb when it changes.

To get around this, you can have `each_run` require or load another file that calls RSpec.configure with the desired filters.

As a side note, if you upgrade to rspec 2.8, you will run into a bug where rspec's filters get clobbered by spork: [rspec-core #554](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/554). I believe this happens regardless of whether you put the filter inline in `each_run` or in an external file.

Comment: Good observation - since posting this I have hit that bug and also found that you can get round it by adding `--tag <tagname>` to the .rspec file to get it to respect `<tagname>`

Comment: Peter's suggestion worked perfectly. I added --tag focus to .rspec and got the :focus feature back.